# Inline expressions in HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

What is the most effective way to write this sql query in HQL

```
select uar.*, (a.default_user_asset_role_id is not null) as is_default  from User_asset_role uar
left outer join account a on a.default_user_asset_role_id = uar.id
where uar.account_id = 3
```

example results

```
1   role_read   Role Read   TRUE
2   role_admin  Role Admin  FALSE
3   role_write  Role Write  FALSE
```

Comment: What do you mean by `(a.default_user_asset_role_id is not null)`?

Comment: account has a property defaultuserAssetRole that is a userAssetRole there might be 15 userAssetRoles only one of which will be the default so for each row I want to return true/false if it is the default

Comment: to better answer your question, since it's a left outer join that column will either be null or it will have a value, where it has a value that means it matches and therefore must be the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HQL's CASE expression:

```
select uar.*, CASE WHEN a.default_user_asset_role_id is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as is_default  from User_asset_role uar
left outer join account a on a.default_user_asset_role_id = uar.id
where uar.account_id = 3
```